# How to handle Python subprocess call error & wait

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am calling a python script (script B) from script A and script B calling another python script script C.

Script A --> Script B --> Script C

Is there a way to make below process to wait for script B & C completion ?

```
import subprocess

cmd = subprocess.call(['python script_A.py'], shell=True)
if cmd != 0:
    print "\nscript_A.py failed with exit code %s\n" % cmd
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: Whatever A does with B is beyond your control, as is what B does with C. If A isn't already waiting for B, you need to rewrite A.

Comment: Why are you using Python 2? Why use subprocess for this, since what you’re calling is just another python module?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `shell=True` with a list, and don't use a list that contains a single string you expect the shell to parse. Just pass a list consisting of the command name and its arguments.

```
result = subprocess.call(['python', 'script_A.py'])
if result != 0:
    ...
```